# Not SharePoint Calendar Overlaying (SharePoint Online)

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer

Hey Guys I'm trying to overlying not SharePoint calendars within a SharePoint site, That you know this something possible ? because I have heard is not possible to overlying exchange calendars or 365 calendars, please let me know your answer ASAP.

thanks,

Answer (score 0):

We can overlay Exchange calendar in sharepoint site.

You can find it directly in the calendar overlay settings.
[image]

But SharePoint does not support overlying office 365 calendars.